# Выбор кандидатов при вызове функций

Tags: c++, функции

Почему в следующем коде `std::swap` не рассматривается в качестве кандидата при вызове `swap` и приходится писать его полностью с пространством имён? Я ожидал, что обе функции (`std::swap` и `smth::swap`) попадут в кандидаты, а дальше выбор сделается на основе пареметров (как при перегрузке функций).

https://ideone.com/JGcZDR

```
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct smth
{
  int x;

  void swap(smth &s)
  {
    ////// error: no matching function for call to ‘smth::swap(int&, int&)’
    ////// note: candidate: void smth::swap(smth&)
    ////// note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
    ////swap(x, s.x);

    std::swap(x, s.x);
  }
};

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так ведь сокрытие имени, или как там оно правильно именуется?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поиск неквалифицированных имен (unqualified name lookup) при вызове функции состоит из двух частей: обычного поиска и ADL-поиска.

- Обычный поиск выполняется "изнутри наружу": из внутренней области видимости во все более и более охватывающие области видимости, пока хотя бы одно имя не найдено. Когда хотя бы одно имя найдено, обычный поиск *немедленно прекращается*.

  Какие области видимости просматриваются зависит от контекста. В вашем случае - это поим имени `swap`, использованного в определении функции-члена класса. Для такого контекста поиск выполняется в следующих областях видимости: локальная, класс `smth`, пространство имен `::`. В процессе просмотра имя `swap` найдется в классе `smth` - это имя вашей же функции. Т.е. до поиска в глобальном пространстве имен дело не доходит вообще.
- ADL-поиск выполняется в пространствах имен, ассоциированных с типами аргументов вызываемой функции. Но в случае фундаментального типа `int` ADL не выполняется - у типа `int` нет ассоциированных пространств имен.

Более интересным был бы пример с

```
struct smth
{
  std::string x;

  void swap(smth &s)
  {
    swap(x, s.x);
  }
};
```

В такой ситуации у типа `std::string` есть ассоциированное с ним пространство имен `std`. И ADL-поиск мог бы выполнить поиск в пространстве имен `std` (даже ваш `using namespace std;` не нужен) и найти там правильный `std::swap`. Однако особое правило unqualified name lookup говорит, что если обычный поиск нашел именно *функцию-член класса*, то ADL не выполняется вообще. Поэтому и здесь будет та же самая ошибка.

Answer (score 3):

Можете добавить using в swap:

```
void swap(smth &s)
{
  using std::swap;
  swap(x, s.x);//ok
}
```

Comment: В общем случае `using` + вызов через неквалифицированное имя `swap` и будет самым правильным варантом, ибо явное указание `std::swap` может отсеять другие функции-кандидаты не из `std`. А это может быть нежелательным.