# Почему ОТКРЫТАЯ функция из родительского класса становится недоступной в ОТКРЫТО унаследованном классе

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, компилятор, стандарт

если в производном классе имеется функция с тем же именем, но различной сигнатурой?

Пример.
Создаем класс `TwoStageMap`, открыто унаследованного от `QMap`:

```
template<typename F, typename S, typename T, typename Cont = QMap<S, T>>
class TwoStageMap : public QMap<F, Cont>
{
public:
    void insert(const F &fkey, const S &skey, const T &value1); //TODO: return an iterator of what?

    void insert(const QPair<F, S> &pair, const T &value1);

    T value(const F &fkey, const S &skey);

    T value(const QPair<F, S> &pair);

};
```

При попытки обратиться к `value()` с сигнатурой из производного класса (`TwoStageMap`) все прекрасно работает:

```
TwoStageMap<int, QString, QString, NamedArgList<QString>> tsMap;

tsMap.insert(31, "October", "Halloween");
tsMap.insert(31, "December", "New Year's Eve");
tsMap.insert(25, "December", "Xmas");
tsMap.insert({25, "October"}, "Canna");

qDebug() << "Day1:" << tsMap.value1(31, "December");
```

, но как только попытаемся вызвать `value()` самого `QMap` (чтобы получить внутренний контейнер под первым ключем), `tsMap.value(31);`, то тут же получаем ошибку:

> no matching member function for call to 'value'

При переименовании функции, например, в `value1()` проблема исчезает.
Вопрос - это ошибка компилятора или стандарт языка?
Компирятор **gcc x86 64bit**

---

Реализация класса, если кто хочет его использовать/попробовать:

```
template<typename F, typename S, typename T, typename Cont>
void TwoStageMap<F,S,T,Cont>::insert(const F &fkey, const S &skey, const T &value)
{
    Cont innerMap;
        if (QMap<F, Cont>::contains(fkey)) {
            innerMap = QMap<F, Cont>::value(fkey);
        }

    innerMap.insert(skey, value);
    QMap<F, Cont>::insert(fkey, innerMap);

    //TODO: return an iterator of what?
}

template<typename F, typename S, typename T, typename Cont>
void TwoStageMap<F,S,T,Cont>::insert(const QPair<F, S> &pair, const T &value)
{
    return insert(pair.first, pair.second, value);
}

template<typename F, typename S, typename T, typename Cont>
T TwoStageMap<F,S,T,Cont>::value(const F &fkey, const S &skey)
{
    auto innerMap = QMap<F, Cont>::value(fkey);
    return innerMap.value(skey);
}

template<typename F, typename S, typename T, typename Cont>
T TwoStageMap<F,S,T,Cont>::value(const QPair<F, S> &pair)
{
    return value1(pair.first, pair.second);
}
```

---

**PS** 
В примере [Вызов функции_члена шаблонного базового класса из функции производного шаблонного класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918162/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3) ситуация с невидимостью **неквалифицированного имени функции** шаблонного родительского класса, с этим, как раз, вопросов нет, у меня, как можно видеть, идет обращение через `QMap<F, Cont>::`, здесь же немного другой случай, а именно, вопрос в том, что мешает компилятору распознать **перегружанную** функцию **с другой сигнатурой**, используя т.н. "искажение имен"? Если это стандарт языка, то вопрос, скорее к [Комитету](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/)

Comment: См. сокрытие имен, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367216/name-hiding-in-c

Comment: @Harry по поводу сокрытия имен, там речь, вроди бы, идет о невертуальной функции с тем же именем и той же сигнатурой

Comment: Код в вопросе изобилует шаблонами, но на самом деле никакого отношения к шаблонам не имеет. Тема, ссылку на которую вы дали, тоже не имеет отношения 
 к данному вопросу. У вас просто происходит обычное сокрытие имен. Этот вопрос уже сто раз задавался. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766450/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При вызове метода класса по имени без квалификатора `tsMap.value(31);` для построения списка перегрузок будет осуществлен поиск имени без квалификатора в области видимости класса `TwoStageMap` согласно спецификации обращения к членам класса:

> **6.4.5 Class member access [basic.lookup.classref]**
>   2 If the id-expression in a class member access (8.5.1.5) is an unqualified-id, and the type of the object expression is of a class type C , the unqualified-id is looked up in the scope of class C.

Этот поиск будет завершен при нахождении имени `value` в классе `TwoStageMap`, так как поиск имени без квалификатора должен завершаться сразу при нахождении первого объявления, согласно спецификации поиска имени без квалификатора:

> **6.4.1 Unqualified name lookup [basic.lookup.unqual]**
>   1 In all the cases listed in 6.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name.

Таким образом метод `value` из базового класса `QMap` в списке перегрузок будет отсутствовать. Чтобы это исправить можно

1. Внести этот метод в область видимости класса `TwoStageMap` добавив

```
using QMap::value;
```

2. При вызове использовать имя с квалификатором:

```
tsMap.QMap::value(31);
```

Comment: исчерпывающий ответ, который возможно тут дать, остальные вопросы к Комитету ;)

Answer (score 5):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то решается эта проблема с помощью `using`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Base
{
public:
    void func(int _v)
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::func;

    void func(const std::string &_str)
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Derived d;
    d.func("text");
    d.func(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Отличный ответ с с практической точки зрения без дурацких переименований! Возможно я его приму, если не получу ответа на "теоретическую" часть, а именно, зачем это понадобилось Комитету не использовать искажение имен при перегрузке функции в производном классе. А пока не хочу демотивировать отвечающих.

Comment: Да, это вариант тот , который вам нужен(насколько я понел). Еще раз_ Комитет по стандарту тут не причем, творец этого сам, создатель языка, Страуструп

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Комитет принимает заявки на улучшение языка (c++11,14,17,,,,)

Answer (score 2):

Не важно какой класс вы напишете. Допустим вы написали такой простой класс:

```
class Your_class {
protected:
    int n{ 3 };
public:
    int value(int n) const { return  n + 3; }
};
```

Если я наследую ваш класс, то я наследую все, что не является закрытым членами вашего класса:

```
class My_class : public Your_class { };
```

В таком виде мой класс имеет функцию_член и обьект `n` вашего класса. Но как только я добавлю в класс:

```
class My_class : public Your_class {
public: 
    bool value(const std::string& s) { return n == s.length(); }
};
```

Этим я выражаю, что  моя  `value`  это совсем другая функция(мне не нужен ваш вариант).  И экземпляры моего класса не будут иметь возможность пользоваться одноименной функцией базового вашего класса. Для обеспечения этой возможности я смогу написать другую функцию, которая вызовит `value` вашего класса, или же сделать так, как описан в другом ответе.

Точно также, если я добавляю в класс свой обьект `n`, то экземпляры моего класса будут пользоваться только этим обьектом. 
Так что, функция=член в производном классе с таким же именем, что и  функция_ член в базовом, не является ее перегрузкой, а является ее заменой

Comment: Отличный упрощенный пример описанного в вопросе поведения. Но вопросы остаются:

`1. Является ли такое поведение частью стандарта языка c++ и где существует ли описание такого поведения в документации стандарта?
2. Что мешает языку не выражать "это другая функция, мне не нужен ваш вариант", а выражать "вижу, что это функция с другой сигнатурой, значить я оставляю и ту, и эту, так как по сути, это разные функции, только для удобства программиста называнные одинаково"?`

Comment: Это является частью самого языка,

Comment: В обратном случаи вы бы не могли написать класс машины, унаследованный от  автомобилей, но которая не   ездит по асфальту,  а работает только в воде. Ну может пример привел неудачный _  из меня преподаватель вышел бы очень плохой...

Comment: Почему не мог бы? Явно бы указал у функции `void move(Road road) = delete`

Comment: Это дает возможность скрыть часть методов базового класса, что  во многих примерах становится  важным инструментом